# Передача ключей ssh по FTP на сетевое устройство

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, ftp, ssh-key

У меня есть сетевое устройство. Чтобы заходить на него без пароля по ssh, мне нужно с пк (с которого будет выполняться вход) передать ключи на устройство. На нём есть утилита для копирования ключей, которая при копировании использует протокол FTP. /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
Вывод копирования ключа по FTP :

```
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)
331 Please specify the password.
230 Login successful.
200 Switching to Binary mode.
213 2610
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa (2610 bytes).
226 Transfer complete.
221 Goodbye.
Key base64 decode failed.
```

То есть, передача файла завершена

> 226 Transfer complete.

но есть ошибка декодирования из base64. На Ubuntu я создаю ключ `"ssh-keygen -t rsa"`.
Была попытка файл /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa с кодировкой us-ascii перекодировать в base64 `base64 /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: ещё нужно разрешение : добавить на сервере этот ключ, как доверенный :  в файл `authorized_keys2` добавить **публичный** ключ.

Comment: @AlexGlebe сервер, в данном случае это сетевое устройство со своей файловой системой, и здесь так сделать не получится. То, что вы описали, я делаю утилитой, которая в свою очередь использует FTP. Проблема в том, что устройство не может раскодировать ключ

Comment: Если есть доступ по паролю, то можно средстами самого ssh скопировать.

Comment: А все-таки: почему вы копируете на устройство закрытый ключ?

Comment: Не мучайтесь с обходными путями. Используйте утилиту ssh-copy-id , хотя первый раз тут пароль запросит от сервера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нужно передавать в качестве открытого ключа файл

```
/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```